# Get the object value based on input objects in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, object

I would like to how to get the value based on input objects in javascript.
If the source matches the currency and also matches the type in paymentin and paymentout in object then get the value of speed and fees

for example 'SGD' with type_in 'credit' and type_out 'bank' should return the speed and fee

Expected Output:

```
id: transfer  credit: 1 days 1% pay_in: pay_out: bank
id: insta debit: 1 days 1.5% pay_in: pay_out: bank
```

I tried but i got stuck

```
function getValue(source,typein,typeout,obj){
  var filterArr = source.filter(function(value){
    return value.country_from.filter(function(payin){
      const in= payin.paymentIn.filter(function(ty){
        return ty.type == typein
     })
      const out = payin.paymentIn.filter(function(ty){
        return ty.type == typeout
     })
   })
 })
}
```

```
var result  = getValue(source,type_in,type_out,obj);
//input objects
var source="SGD";
var type_in="credit";
var type_out="bank";
var obj = [{
    "id": "transfer",
    "country_from": [{
        "currency": [
            "SGD",
            "USD"
        ],
        "paymentIn": [{
            "type": "credit",
            "speed": {
                "unit": "days",
                "number": "1"
            },
            "fee": {
                "type": "%",
                "number": "1"
            }
        }],
        "paymentOut": [{
            "type": "bank",
            "speed": {
                "unit": "days",
                "number": "2"
            }
       }]
    }]
}, {
    "id": "insta",
    "country_from": [{
        "currency": [
            "SGD",
            "USD"
        ],
        "paymentIn": [{
            "type": "credit",
            "speed": {
                "unit": "days",
                "number": "1"
            },
            "fee": {
                "type": "%",
                "number": "1.5"
            }
        }],
       "paymentOut": [{
            "type": "bank",
            "speed": {
                "unit": "days",
                "number": "2"
            }
       }]
    }]
}]
```

Comment: getting confused with Expected Output, is this really expected or unformatted?

Comment: But why is the 2nd row with 'id: insta ... ' part of the result? It has a paymentIn type of debit, whereas the input asks for credit?

Comment: @wentjun thanks for prompt reply, will update changes

Comment: @Harish thanks for prompt reply, i should get the output as paymentin values and paymentout values to the corresponding source,type_in and type_out

Comment: @sowmiya I have posted my reply. It should work. I will try to format it

Comment: @wentjun thanks a lot for the answer, what if the paymentin has one more type debit and paymentout is banktransfer how to get the value ,if passing getValue('SGD', 'debit', 'bank', obj);

Comment: @sowmiya you mean, if `paymentIn` has more than one object in the array?

Comment: @wentjun yes if paymentIn has more than one object in array

Comment: @sowmiya You can use array.some() to check if the object with the type matches, and then you can use filter() to get that object. I have updated my answer, let me know if that is something similar to what you are looking for

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have made some mistakes on your initial code, but I guess it is due to the confusion of dealing with so many layers of objects and arrays. This is what you should do:

```
const getValue = (source, typein, typeout, obj) => {

  const res = obj.map(item => {
    if (item['country_from'][0]['paymentIn'][0]['type'] === typein 
        && item['country_from'][0]['currency'].includes(source) 
        && item['country_from'][0]['paymentOut'][0]['type'] === typeout) {
      return `id: ${item['id']} credit: ${item['country_from'][0]['paymentIn'][0]['speed']['number']} days credit: ${item['country_from'][0]['paymentIn'][0]['fee']['number']}${item['country_from'][0]['paymentIn'][0]['fee']['type']} pay_in: pay_out: ${item['country_from'][0]['paymentOut'][0]['speed']['number']}`
    }
  });
  return res;

}

getValue('SGD', 'credit', 'bank', obj);
```

Basically, I will iterate through every element of the input array, `obj` (which is the one you posted on your question), and within each iteration, I check for the following 3 conditions using the if statement.

1) The `paymentIn` `type` matches `typein`

2) The `paymentOut` `type` matches `typein`

3) `currency` contains `source`

Elements that fulfil the above 3 conditions will the string result.

---

EDIT: To answer your question on the comments, if the `paymentIn` array has more than one object, we can use Array.some() to check if the object with the `type` property has the same value as `typeIn`.

```
if (item['country_from'][0]['paymentIn'].some(payment => payment['type']===typein) 
  && item['country_from'][0]['currency'].includes(source) 
  && item['country_from'][0]['paymentOut'][0]['type'] === typeout) {

  // to get the object with that typein
  const filteredPaymentIn = item['country_from'][0]['paymentIn'].filter(payment => payment['type']===typein)[0];

}
```